# Immediate Propagation in Active Directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2003

It's been a while since I've done any large-scale AD administration so I'm reaching back a bit here.  I remember that there are certain security related attributes on a user account object that, due to their nature, are flagged for immediate propagation to other sites.

I have a case where passwords resets are not being propagated until scheduled replication happens.  I had thought that was a case of immediate propagation.  Am I just remembering incorrectly?

Domain function level is 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the urgent replication section here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772726(WS.10).aspx#w2k3tr_repup_how_huzs

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for as I was posting!

Comment: glad to help...

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you are, passwords are propagated on the normal schedule. I'll connect to a DC in the site closest to the user when I need it to take immediate effect or when I forget I'll jump into Sites and Services and force a replication to the site the user is in.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the confirmation!  Accept to joeqwerty, though, for the link.